# Obscure MySql Connector/J error message - java.sql.SQLException: boo {exclamation mark}

Tags: mysql, spring

What the hey does this MySql error message mean?

```
java.sql.SQLException: boo!

springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: CallableStatementCallback; SQL [{call sp_MyStoredProc(?, ?, ?)}]; boo!
```

It's not particularly meaningful that's for sure. Has anybody come across this and is able to translate to less lazy~developer~ish...?

I am accessing via `org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure`

I am using `org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.3`

@Update

The offending lines are in CallableStatetement.java (2269-2271)

```
if (!found) {
     throw SQLError.createSQLException("boo!", "S1000", this.connection.getExceptionInterceptor());`
}
```

Attching the sources for mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar and tracing though the code reveal that the correct message should be along the lines of 'mismatch between declared and actual parameters' or similar.

Indeed correctly declaring my output parameter

```
declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("output", Types.INTEGER));
```

rather than

```
declareParameter(new SqlParameter("output", Types.INTEGER));
```

fixed my problem. But a more meaningful error message would have saved precious time. I shall make this suggestion to the MySql Connector/J Development team.

Comment: Somebody has customized the error message I guess !

Comment: I have upgraded to mysql-connector-java-5.1.25 but the error message remains the same. Accessing a Stored Procedure from Java is surely not edge case.

Comment: Have you tried searching your entire codebase for the word "boo!" I have a hard time believing the Java people would release code with a "boo!" message.

Comment: Me neither - and yet there it is...

Comment: I am having the same problem. Anyone found out what it is?

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the update to the question this is commonly caused by incorrectly using a CallableStatement. For example:

Stored Procedure uses 2 parameters, one in and one out:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`example`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_getSensorLocation`(IN in_id VARCHAR(128), OUT loc VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
SELECT LOCATION INTO loc FROM table.SENSORS
WHERE ID = in_id;
END
```

but the call to it only uses 1:

```
private String getSensorLocation(String sensorID) {    
    String location = "";
    Connection c = dbr.getConnection();
    String prepStatement = "{ call sp_getSensorLocation(?) } ";
    try {
         callableStatement cs = c.prepareCall(prepStatement);
         cs.setString(1, sensorID);
         ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
         if (rs.next()) {
            location = rs.getString(1);
            }
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
                LOG.error("Error:", ex);
         }        
    dbr.closeConnection(c, rs, cs);
    return location;
}
```

When the correct code is really:

```
private String getSensorLocation(String sensorID) {
    String location = "";
    Connection c = dbr.getConnection();
    String prepStatement = "{ call sp_getSensorLocation(?, ?) } ";
    try {
        CallableStatement cs = c.prepareCall(prepStatement);
        cs.setString(1, sensorID);
        cs.execute();
        location = cs.getString(2);            
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        LOG.error("Error:", ex);
    }
    dbr.closeConnection(c, rs, cs);
    return location;
}
```

Notice I also changed to cs.execute as I don't expect a result set and would have issues with this as well (the example is taken from someone else's code I'm fixing, the joys -_-)