# MySQL User Defined Procedure Returns "boo!" when called

Tags: mysql

ere is a summation of my procedure code.

Everything runs, except the call statement:

```
call rlbsddb.Get_TD_Roles('userid', 'dbname', 'tblname', '@TS')
Error Message Returned: boo!
```

I know MySQL has bad error messaging, but 'boo!'???

The overall goal of the code, is to run 3 statements gathering details about access. Return the DateTime of the insertion, and then use that pull the actual results.

Actual results is anywhere from 0-10 rows which were inserted in the code. 
Why isn't this working?

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS rlbsddb.Get_TD_Roles$$

create PROCEDURE rlbsddb.Get_TD_Roles (in pEID varchar(30), 
                in pDBName varchar(30), in pTBLName varchar(30), out RUN_TS datetime)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN

set @CURR_TS = current_timestamp;
select @CURR_TS into RUN_TS;

/* Do Some Stuff */
/* Original Code uses variables to locate a multiple row response 
   Multiple row response is then added into the tmp_for_example_only table
   and after call, information is pulled using a select */

insert into rlbsddb.tmp_for_example_only
select pEID, pDBName, pTBLName, @CURR_TS;

END $$

call rlbsddb.Get_TD_Roles('userid', 'dbname', 'tblname', @TS)$$
/* I've tried this with '@TS' as well */
/* I've also tried "show warnings$$" in front of the call and just after the call, nothing returned */

select * 
from rlbsddb.tmp_for_example_only
where inserted_dtim = @TS
and user_id = 'userid'
and DBName = 'dbname'
and TBLName = 'tblname'$$
```

Comment: [Possible dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813517/obscure-mysql-connector-j-error-message-java-sql-sqlexception-boo-exclamatio).